# How to append button dynamically to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code

```
<div class="EquipmentContent row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 subSection" style="float:right;background:#dff0ff;">         
        <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 cl-md-1 col-lg-1">
          <button type="button" style="display: inline-block;float:right;" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="hideEquipmentDetails()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here am loading div data dynamically

```
var content= response.data.filters;
$.each(content,function(i,value){ 
    $('.subSection').html('<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 cl-md-2 col-lg-2"><label class="equipmentHeaderlable">Name</label><label class="equipmentHeaderValues">'+value.name+'</label></section>').appendTo('.EquipmentContent');
});
```

Its looping through correctly but only first object is displayed.(i.e I have 6 names in an array but its showing only 1st name).why so?I tried by adding scroll and height also.

One more thing how can I append this section dynamically?

```
<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 cl-md-1 col-lg-1">
<button type="button" style="display: inline-block;float:right;" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="hideEquipmentDetails()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `html()` in a loop. `html()` clears all existing content and applies whatever you provided in its place. This is why only the last item in your loop is visible.

To fix this, use `append()` instead.

```
var content= response.data.filters;
$.each(content,function(i,value){ 
  $('.subSection').append('<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 cl-md-2 col-lg-2"><label class="equipmentHeaderlable">Name</label><label class="equipmentHeaderValues">' + value.name + '</label></section>').appendTo('.EquipmentContent');
});
```

You can use the same method, `append()`, to add the content in your second example to the DOM too.

Comment: I want header labels only one time..then values should be looped.how can I get this?

Comment: Append the labels outside the loop, append the values inside the loop

Comment: :-(  can you give me some example?

Comment: Not really as you haven't shown what the HTML output should look like, however you already have the code to loop and to append, so I'm not sure what further assistance I can offer.